# Failed to open stream: Permission denied when executing fopen after post request

Tags: php, curl, file-permissions, permission-denied

I have php code as follows.

```
<?php  
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "[HIDDEN]");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("code" => "print(1+1)"));
  
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  echo $result;
?>
```

Whose post request goes to...

```
 <?php  
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') {
     $code = $_POST['code'];
     $handle = fopen("canvas.py", "w");
     fwrite($handle, $code);
     $out = shell_exec("python canvas.py");
     echo $out;
   }
 ?>
```

My goal here is to simply send a post request to another php file, with the post sent, open a file and write that code to it. Then, echo back the output which should be 2. Sorry if my jargon is incorrect.

I keep getting the error "Failed to open stream: Permission denied" because of fopen(). I can use fopen in the same file, but when the code from the first file triggers the second, I get this error.

They are in the same directory, I have set permissions of each file with chmod 777 {filename}, including the canvas.py file. Lastly, not sure if it matters but I am executing the first code with "php file1.php" in a linux server not owned by me.

Comment: What are permissions of python script? This also is extremely dangerous. Anyone could take control of your computer if this did work (given the right permission sets).

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx. There a less dangerous way? I need to check if the code compiles for what I'm doing.

Comment: Well `python canvas.py` is going to run the script so anything anyone sends to this script would be executed. In PHP I'd run it with the lint (`-l`) flag which would verify the syntax. Looks like `python -m` might be the equivalent. Can your user execute the python script separate from python?

Comment: Thanks will do that. I was able to ```fopen``` from the first file but not the second. You mean separate from php? If so I can do that too with ```python {py file name}```.

Answer (score 0):

Found it out, just had to change the permission of the web server to execute files.